# Multilingual app name in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, multilingual

I've noticed that the default Windows 8 apps change their names when the system language changes. I'd like to ask how to achieve this with my app? I couldn't find a way to specify it in the app manifest, it seems that it doesn't allow for multiple display names.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull your applcation DisplayName from your multilingual resource files.

In appxmanifest:

```
<DisplayName>ms-resource:AppTitle</DisplayName>
```

In your Resources.resw:

```
AppTitle    MyAppTitle
```

Comment: yeah, I found that a while ago and it works, but I forgot to answer my own question here :-) anyway, thanks!